# Bokeh run service as daemon

Tags: bokeh

To deploy a bokeh application, I have a server where I run

```
bokeh serve --allow-websocket-origin=myurl:5006 BokehMain.py
```

However, I want to run bokeh as a daemon so I can close the terminal and let the app run as a service in the background.

**Question**
Is it necessary to set up an apache server for bokeh if I want users to connect through the webbrowser instead of an SSH tunnel. (as described in [this link](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#userguide-server-deployment))

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I tried the same command with nohup but it still binds the process to the ssh session. I don't get the command line back after the command and the process terminates when I close the terminal window

Comment: Your question is not related to Bokeh in any way. To run commands in the background use `nohup %program name and arguments% &` pattern - read more e.g. here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/difference-between-nohup-disown-and . To be able to connect to your instance of Bokeh you just have to make sure that your server where you run Bokeh is accessible from the outside via the ports that you assign to Bokeh application and that Bokeh uses by itself. This applies to any kind of server, not just Bokeh, so you would have the same question if you used Apache server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
nohup bokeh serve --allow-websocket-origin=myurl:5006 BokehMain.py
```

`nohup`, short for '*no hang up*' is a command in Linux systems that keep processes running even after exiting the shell or terminal.

So, even after you close the terminal, `nohup` command will continue to run the bokeh server in background.

Comment: Nohup, short for no hang up is a command in Linux systems that keep processes running even after exiting the shell or terminal.